# Anonymous inner class v/s singleton class

Tags: java, singleton, anonymous

What I understand from anonymous inner class is that it is used for defining and creating a object "on-the-fly-use-and-throw" and using the overridden methods. If this is being used multiple times across the program can this be a candidate for refactoring to singleton class?

Answer (score 4):

IMO, such a class is certainly a candidate for refactoring into a named class.

It is unlikely, though, that you'll want it to be a singleton, precisely.  In the singleton pattern, there is only one instance of a class in existence at once.  This is contrary to the usual cases where anonymous classes are used; they are generally instantiated freely and often associated with the containing class in ways that would be inappropriate for a singleton.